# What backpack skin is this?

Tags: guild-wars-2

What backpack skin is this? I haven't seen it before and the guy didn't speak English!

If you right click on the image and *Open image in new tab*, you can see the skin much better.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the newer crafting profession backpacks.  With the pots and pans, looks like it's one for chefs.

Here's a link to a match: [Ambrosial Chef's Backpack](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Ambrosial_Chef%27s_Backpack)

Comment: That's the one, cheers man!